# Having issues calculating and displaying the number of elements in an XQuery doc using the count() function

Tags: xml, xquery

been working on my first XQuery project and I was instructed to create 3 simple queries. Most of them are supposed to calculate the number of certain crimes in DC (in this case, robbery). The way the textbook explains it is a bit confusing (it said to use "count", as in count the number of offenses), but it says to **count the number of elements** for that offense, so the result document should show that there are 1030 robberies committed over the period of time recorded in the sample database/xml file. When I run the query, neither "ROBBERY" nor the count shows up.

Here is my code:

```
    xquery version "1.0";

(: 
   Query to display the total number of incidents for 
   crimes specified by the user    
 :)

declare variable $crimeType as xs:string external;
declare variable $crimes := doc('dc_crime.xml');

<results>{
    <incidents type="$crimeType">
        crimeCount="{
        count(doc('dc_crime.xml')//crimes[crimeType='ROBBERY'])
        }">
        {
        doc('dc_crime.xml')//crimes[crimeType='ROBBERY']
        }
    </incidents>

}</results>
```

Part of the XML file:

```
    <crimes>
   <crime id="5047867">
      <dateTime>2013-06-05T00:00:00</dateTime>
      <month>6-Jun</month>
      <day>4-Wed</day>
      <offense>SEX ABUSE</offense>
      <method>KNIFE</method>
      <ward>4</ward>
   </crime>
   <crime id="7083463">
      <dateTime>2013-07-08T00:00:00</dateTime>
      <month>7-Jul</month>
      <day>2-Mon</day>
      <offense>SEX ABUSE</offense>
      <method>OTHERS</method>
      <ward>1</ward>
   </crime>
   <crime id="11010107">
      <dateTime>2013-07-31T00:00:00</dateTime>
      <month>7-Jul</month>
      <day>4-Wed</day>
      <offense>HOMICIDE</offense>
      <method>OTHERS</method>
      <ward>5</ward>
   </crime>
   <crime id="11250281">
      <dateTime>2013-07-08T00:00:00</dateTime>
      <month>7-Jul</month>
      <day>2-Mon</day>
      <offense>SEX ABUSE</offense>
      <method>OTHERS</method>
      <ward>7</ward>
   </crime>
   <crime id="12055744">
      <dateTime>2013-08-19T00:00:00</dateTime>
      <month>8-Aug</month>
      <day>2-Mon</day>
      <offense>SEX ABUSE</offense>
      <method>OTHERS</method>
      <ward>1</ward>
   </crime>
   <crime id="12174206">
      <dateTime>2013-08-26T00:00:00</dateTime>
      <month>8-Aug</month>
      <day>2-Mon</day>
      <offense>SEX ABUSE</offense>
      <method>OTHERS</method>
      <ward>1</ward>
   </crime>
   <crime id="13069723">
      <dateTime>2013-07-23T00:00:00</dateTime>
      <month>7-Jul</month>
      <day>3-Tue</day>
      <offense>SEX ABUSE</offense>
      <method>OTHERS</method>
      <ward>7</ward>
   </crime>
```

Can someone please provide any tips? Thank you.

Comment: There is no `crimeType` element in the XML posted here... maybe you want something like this : `count(doc('dc_crime.xml')//crimes/crime[offense='ROBBERY'])` ?

Comment: @har07:

It asked me to declare an external variable called, "crimeType". Thank you.

Comment: okay, that's not the way you reference the external variable. I guess the book want to filter by that external variable, something like : `.....[offense=$crimeType])`

Comment: Like this?:

`declare variable $crimeType as xs:string external;
declare variable $crimes := doc('dc_crime.xml');

<results>{
 <incidents type="$crimeType"
  crimeCount="{
  count(doc('dc_crime.xml')//crimes[offense'$crimeType])
  }">
 </incidents>

}</results>`
still no change, sadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should work:

```
xquery version "1.0";

(: 
   Query to display the total number of incidents for 
   crimes specified by the user    
 :)

declare variable $crimeType as xs:string external;

declare function local:countCrimes($crimeType as xs:string) as element(results) {

  let $crimes := doc('dc_crime.xml')//crime[offense = $crimeType]
  let $count := count($crimes)  
  return
    if ($count > 0 ) then
      <results>
          <incidents type="{$crimeType}" crimeCount="{$count}">{$crimes}</incidents>
      </results>
    else
      <results>No crimes found for that crime type.</results>
};
local:countCrimes($crimeType)
```

Comment: Just realized I didn't use the external variable, I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct query.

```
declare variable $crimeType as xs:string external;
 declare variable $crimes := doc('dc_crime.xml')/crimes/crime;


<results>
    <incidents type="{$crimeType}">
        {
        count
        (for $c in $crimes
        where $c/offense = $crimeType
        return $c)
        }
    </incidents>
</results>
```

Remember when you run external variable using Saxon you have to set the value of external variable "*parameter=value*", parameter is the name of the external variable don't add the "*$*" symbol, value is the "*variable*".
Your Java command in command prompt should look like:

```
java -cp saxon9he.jar net.sf.saxon.Query dc_query1.xq crimeType=ROBBERY -o:dc_results1.xml
```

or you will get error like "No value supplied for required parameter crimeType
Query failed with dynamic error: No value supplied for required parameter crimeType" if you don't include the external variable.